# Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Tags: php

hola alguien me puede ayuder con el siguiente error:
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

se supone que donde me marca el error es en esta linea:

```html
$_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       
        $_SESSION['MM_iduser'] = $LoginRS["iduser"];  
        if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
          $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl']; 
        }
        header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
      }// aqui me marca que hay un error
```

```html
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['email'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "accesook.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "acceso_erro.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysqli_select_db($catalogo,$database_catalogo);
  
  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT `email`, `password` FROM Bodegeros WHERE `email`=%s AND `password`=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 
   
  $LoginRS = mysqli_query($catalogo,$LoginRS__query) or die(mysqli_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysqli_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";
    
 if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       
    $_SESSION['MM_iduser'] = $LoginRS["iduser"];  
    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl']; 
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array
```

Utiliza mysqli_fetch_assoc o mysqli_fetch_array para obtener una fila de resultados como una array asociativo.

```
$query = "SELECT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$followingdata = $result->fetch_assoc()
```

Otra alternativa:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios where usuario_id = 278");
$followingdata = $result->fetch_assoc();
var_dump($followingdata);
die();
```

O
    $followingdata = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Comment: hola ya le intente y fallo:
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query()

Comment: @JavierJoasimarPalosFlores agregue en la respuesta otra forma usando mysqli_query